# Docker pull doesnt find `latest` tag

Tags: docker

When trying to pull the official image for RNA-seq aligner STAR with
`docker pull alexdobin/star`

I got an error despite copying the *Docker Pull Command* as shown in the screenshot (lower right)

[image: star_docker]

The error was the following:

`Error response from daemon: manifest for alexdobin/star:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you don't specify the tag as part of the image name in the docker command then it is assumed that you are referring to the `latest` tag.

Further, as there is [no image with tag `latest` present in the repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/alexdobin/star/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated), you get the error as expected:

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for alexdobin/star:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Change the tag to one of the available ones and it will work as expected:

```
docker pull alexdobin/star:2.6.1d
```

Comment: I've already answered my own question :) but thanks, I just forgot to mark it.

Comment: it was missing the explanation so I thought it would make sense to describe the problem as well along with the solution :-)

Comment: I see, I'm still unsure why it doesn't automatically pick up the most recent tag available.

Comment: probably because different docker images can have different naming convention for tags and thus it is not easy to figure out which is the actual recent one.

Answer (score 0):

You can open just the tab `Tags` and copy the pull command as shown in the screenshot (bottom right).

[image: pull_with_tag]

It worked just fine.